# Show dashboard groups depending on role (without acl groups)

Tags: php, symfony, roles, sonata-admin, sonata

I'm trying to show a number of sections on the dashboard, depending on the role from the user that's logged in.

I don't work with ACL Groups or something like that. I just have in my security.yml:

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_COMPANY:     ROLE_USER
    ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_COMPANY, ROLE_USER]
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
```

I can login and show data in my list view (example overview of jobs) depending on the role from the user who is logged in.

Now I would like to hide a section on my dashboard when the logged in user is not an admin.

In my admin.yml I have:

```
services:
    sonata.admin.jobs:
        class: MyBundleName\Admin\JobAdmin
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Job Manager", label: "Jobs", roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        arguments:
            - ~
            - MyBundleName\Entity\Job
            -
        calls:
            - [ setTranslationDomain, [MyBundleName]]
            - [ setTemplate, [show, MyBundleName:Job:base_show.html.twig]]

    sonata.admin.applications:
        class: MyBundleName\Admin\ApplicationAdmin
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Job Manager", label: "Applications" }
        arguments:
            - ~
            - MyBundleName\Entity\Application
            -
        calls:
            - [ setTranslationDomain, [MyBundleName]]

    sonata.admin.categories:
        class: MyBundleName\Admin\CategoryAdmin
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Job Extra", label: "Categories" }
        arguments:
            - ~
            - MyBundleName\Entity\Category
            -
        calls:
            - [ setTranslationDomain, [MyBundleName]]

    sonata.admin.skills:
        class: MyBundleName\Admin\SkillAdmin
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Job Extra", label: "Skills" }
        arguments:
            - ~
            - MyBundleName\Entity\Skill
            -
        calls:
            - [ setTranslationDomain, [MyBundleName]]
```

As you can see I have 2 groups "Job Manager" and "Job Extra". I would like to hide the group "Job extra" if the logged in user is not an admin.
But what's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can check your user role directly in your Twig with:

`{% if is_granted('ROLE_USER') %}
    <div>Only show this<div>
{% endif %}`

Comment: He's using the twig helper "sonata_block_render" so I can't really now which block is loaded ..